# trap an event raised by a reflected dll

Tags: c#, events, reflection

I have a desktop C# app.

I load a DLL dynamically.

I attach to an event.

I now want to trap the event in my app.

So, this is the DLL I am reflecting:

```
namespace injectdll
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public delegate void delResponseEvent(string message);
        public static event delResponseEvent ResponseEvent;
        public static void hello()
        {
            if (ResponseEvent != null)
            {
                ResponseEvent("hello andy");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is part of my desktop app:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\testbytes\injectdll\injectdll\bin\Debug\injectdll.dll");
            Assembly program = Assembly.Load(bytes);
            Type type = program.GetType("injectdll.Class1");
            var flags = BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public;
            MethodInfo Method = type.GetMethod("hello", flags);
            var eventInfo = type.GetEvent("ResponseEvent", flags);               
            type.InvokeMember("hello", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, System.Type.DefaultBinder, "", null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

I now need something like this:

```
private void FunctionInMyDEsktopApp(string message)
{
   //this has been raised in my DLL
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an event handler with `eventInfo.AddEventHandler` already?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet hi, thanks for that suggestion. I am looking at it now

Comment: I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228976%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @AliSepehri.Kh hi, thanks. yes i saw that too. MSDN being MSDN they do not give a clear answer to what I need. This took me so far but then no more.Thank you though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
...
var eventInfo = type.GetEvent( "ResponseEvent", flags );
var d = Delegate.CreateDelegate( eventInfo.EventHandlerType, this,
                                 "FunctionInMyDEsktopApp" )
eventInfo.AddEventHandler( null, d );
...
```

Since you don't have the type of the delegate either, you can get it using `EventInfo.EventHandlerType`. More information about `AddEventHandler` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.eventinfo.addeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Oh Pieter beat me to it.

Comment: I had seen that page before but did not find it helpful to me. It seems complex to my needs?

Comment: thanks./ I have just done so. This is the error: Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.

Comment: Hi, I got it to work. I had to remove 'Static' from my function in my client handler.  thanks

Comment: You could probably also have removed the `this` from the CreateDelegate call. I wrote it like that because it wasn't static in your example code!

Comment: You are quite. I was mucking around the code and did not give an accurate version of my code. You gave me a solution and your time and I am v grateful